# Convert delimited text to csv

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert the file containing delimiter "|" to excel file using VBA. My code is working when I used the constant path location. But, I got an error if I used the value from the textbox wherein the user will select the location of the file.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
Dim File1 As String

Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

File1 = txtBox.Text

With wb.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;File1" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "sample"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

The File1 is the location of the file. It can be change depending on the location of the txt file. If I change it to example "C:\Users\sample.txt", it is working fine. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Error:
[image]

Also, how can I change the value of **.Name** using the selected file from the textbox instead of hardcoded it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
 "TEXT;File1" _
```

to

```
"TEXT;" & File1 _
```